# Issue with generating output PDF using lopdf library in Rust

Tags: rust

I’m trying to use the lopdf library in Rust to compress the content streams of a PDF file. Here’s the code I’m using:

```rust
use lopdf::{Document, Object, Stream, dictionary};

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let mut doc = Document::load("input.pdf")?;
    let pages = doc.get_pages();

    for (_, page) in pages {
        let content = doc.get_page_content(page).unwrap();
        let mut stream = Stream::new(dictionary! {}, content.clone());
        stream.compress().unwrap();
        let stream_obj = Object::Stream(stream);
        doc.objects.insert(page.contents_index, stream_obj);
    }

    doc.save("output.pdf")?;
    Ok(())
}
```

However, when I run this code, the output PDF file is always blank or unreadable. I’ve tried debugging the issue by commenting out the compression step but it's still getting corrupted.

I suspect that I'm doing something wrong with `get_page_content()` but I don't really know what

Has anyone else encountered this issue or have any suggestions on how to resolve it?

Comment: nope :/ nothing

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `page.contents_index` it should be `page`

```
for (_, page) in pages {
    let content = doc2.get_page_content(page).unwrap();
    let mut stream = Stream::new(dictionary! {}, content.clone());
    stream.compress().unwrap();
    let stream_obj = Object::Stream(stream);

    doc2.objects.insert(page, stream_obj);  
}

doc2.save("output.pdf").unwrap();
```